# Аналог toggleClass для удаления/создания DOM-элемента

Tags: jquery

Существует ли какое-нибудь решение для удаления элемента, если он существует, и создания, если его нет? По аналогии с toggleClass или toggleFade. Эти два способа не подходят т.к. скрывают элемент визуально, но на уровне DOM он сохраняется.

Comment: нет, такого из коробки нет, но всегда можно написать самому

Answer (score 1):

Скрытие элемента через класс - это обратимый и переключаемый процесс, а полное удаление - необратимый.

Однако вы можете сохранить ваш элемент в js, чтобы в будущем снова вставить его в DOM. Подходящий пример есть в документации к методу jquery `detach()` (https://api.jquery.com/detach/), он вам подойдет.

```
var p;
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  if ( p ) {
    p.appendTo( "body" );
    p = null;
  } else {
    p = $( "p" ).detach();
  }
});
```

Также вместо `detach()` вы можете использовать метод `remove()`, который также удалит элемент из DOM, но еще со всеми привязанными к нему обработчиками событий.

Comment: _а полное удаление - необратимый_ не совсем :-)

Comment: @Grundy, то есть удаленный из DOM элемент где-то все же остается?

Comment: Единственная разница между detach и remove, это то, что при применении remove удаляются навешанные обработчики событий

Comment: собственно об этом как раз первая строка в справке: _The **.detach()** method is the **same as .remove()**, except that .detach() keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements. _

Comment: Пока не совсем понимаю, почему в этом случае удаление элемента из DOM не считается необратимым процессом :(

Comment: Хотя бы потому, что удаленный элемент можно вставить обратно

Comment: Если предварительно сохранить его в js? А, кажется понял, вы имеете ввиду, что в данном случае одинаково подойдет и `detach()`, и `remove()`, верно?

Comment: ага, я же про это и написал во втором комментарии :-)